# How can I change hidden state activation size in RNN using Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to train an RNN with a different size of hidden state activation than provided by default in keras. example: my input vector at time step is size 27 and output is also 27. I want hidden state activation size to be 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you mean by *hidden state activation size*. The parameter that controls the RNN cell size in keras is called `units`. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#simplernncell):

> - **units**: Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space.

This number directly corresponds to the shape of the recurrent matrix that is applied inside the cell, so in this sense it is a *hidden size* of the cell, or the number of *hidden neurons*.

To change this size from `27` to `50` simply call:

```
model.add(SimpleRNN(50, ...))
```

Comment: Units corresponds to the dimension of output vector. What I want is my output vector to be of length 27 but hidden state to be of size 50.

Comment: I'm afraid, neither simple RNN, nor LSTM/GRU work that way. You have to write own RNN cell with an additional hidden layer inside.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just wanted to confirm whether something is available or not. I am implementing it using Tensorflow.

Comment: Rnn actually do have an hidden state dimension which could differ from the output one. W_hy and W_hx are separate NN inside the cell and they can have a different dimension than the out NN.